# Melzi 2.0 Board Firmware Upload problem

Tags: uploading, avrdude, firmware, avr-gcc

I'm trying to flash the repetier Firmware to my Prusa i3 3D Printer, which uses Melzi 2.0 board. I uploaded it successfully 2 days ago with same settings  but now is failing always.

```
@avrdude -p m1284p -b57600 -c arduino -P COM%x% -e -U flash:w:%filename%.hex
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9705 (probably m1284p)
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "newa.hex"
avrdude: input file newa.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (114266 bytes):
Writing |                                                    | 0% 0.00s
avrdude: stk500_paged_write(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x64 
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [Electronics Stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) question *[avrdude error - stk500_paged_write() protocol error](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/67945)* has answers that suggest three different tactics for protocol errors:

• Upgrade the Arduino IDE from 1.00 to 1.05, or install "AVR-GCC Toolchain" via Homebrew;
• Disconnect everything from TX / RX (Arduino digital pins 0 and 1);
• Use shorter or different USB cables, hooked to a USB port on computer instead of on a hub

I've seen dozens of answers here on arduino.stackexchange with such suggestions, as well as webpages elsewhere with ideas like those in [an answer to *AVRDUDE Error (Arduino Leonardo)*](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=84566.0).

You could go through this list of programmer-is-not-responding arduino.stackexchange questions, and report back on what works and what doesn't:

• ["avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00," aka Some Dude Named Avr Won't Let Me Upload My Program](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17),
• [How do I resolve "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17827),
• [avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding after serial](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/33182),
• [avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding + avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x47](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/18988),
• [avrdude: stk500_rcv :programmer is not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/18172),
• [Arduino Nano Update failure - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/25122),
• [avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/1585),
• [Arduino Uno cannot upload any sketch: avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17985),
• ["avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding" when uploading sketch](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/28600),
• [Arduino not working / not uploading [duplicate]](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/18993),
• [Problems uploading sketch to Arduino Due](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/12540),
• [FTDI stdk 500k not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/20656),
• [Arduino Prototype on Breadboard: "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/22304),
• [Arduino Nano - programmer is not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/18194),
• [How do I resolve "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17827/how-do-i-resolve-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-responding),
• [Arduino not in sync unique error](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/23552),
• [Arduino nano stopped working](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/13620),
• [Not in sync: resp=0x00](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/5022),
• [How to troubleshoot the Arduino Mini and Arduino usb2serial?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/15921),
• [Atmega328P-PU: Programmer is not responding](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/12104),

Note, click the “see more linked questions…” link in the sidebar to get a nice webpage with the above list and the opening lines of each question.